# Evenly space three buttons inside a fieldset

Tags: html, css

So I just want to even space out three buttons along the bottom and not having any luck... Can anyone help with the CSS?

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Am8vc/

I would all three buttons to be below the lowest input field and evenly spaced between the left and right borders of the fieldset. So far the best I can do is get them to display inline...

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" id="formElem1" method="post" name="formElem">    <fieldset class="step">
        <legend>Search</legend>        
        <table class="inlineTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="OriginalStatNum">Life Master</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input class="AlphaNumOnly" id="OriginalStatNum" maxlength="10" name="OriginalStatNum" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>             
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ReportsToStat">Reports to Stat</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input class="AlphaNumOnly" id="ReportsToStat" maxlength="1" name="ReportsToStat" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="OriginalMarketSegment">Market Segment</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input class="AlphaNumOnly" id="OriginalMarketSegment" maxlength="3" name="OriginalMarketSegment" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                          
                </td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="Pensgc">PENSGC</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input class="AlphaNumOnly" id="Pensgc" maxlength="3" name="Pensgc" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                         
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="OriginalName">Name (If No Life Master)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <input class="AlphaNumOnly" id="OriginalName" maxlength="255" name="OriginalName" style="width:160px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                       
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="OriginalEffectiveDate">Effective Date</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Effective Date must be a date." id="OriginalEffectiveDate" name="OriginalEffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="OriginalCancelDate">Cancel Date</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Cancel Date must be a date." id="OriginalCancelDate" name="OriginalCancelDate" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ExceptionName">Exception List</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <select id="ExceptionName" name="ExceptionName"><option value=""> </option>
<option value="C">Starting with C</option>
<option value="D">Starting with D</option>
<option value="T">LStarting with T</option>
<option value="A">Starting with A</option>
<option value="N">Starting with N</option>
<option value="X">WHATEVER</option>
</select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="LastUpdateId">Last Update By</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="LastUpdateId" name="LastUpdateId" readonly="readonly" style="width: 80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>                
        </table>       
        <table class="inlineTable" style="margin-right: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="AgencyName">Agency Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input class="noInput" id="AgencyName" name="AgencyName" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="CompanyCode">Company Code</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="CompanyCode" name="CompanyCode" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="SecSellerCd">SEC Seller Code</label>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="SecSellerCd" name="SecSellerCd" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="DssMrktSeg">Market Segment</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="DssMrktSeg" name="DssMrktSeg" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="LifeAnn">Life/Annuity</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="LifeAnn" name="LifeAnn" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ConnCode">Contract Code</label>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="ConnCode" name="ConnCode" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="CancelRsn" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;">Cancel RSN</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="CancelRsn" name="CancelRsn" readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ReportsToAgn">Reports to Agency</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="ReportsToAgn" name="ReportsToAgn" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <span class="ButtonContainer">
            <button type="submit" class="submitButton" >Search</button>
            <button type="submit" class="submitButton" >Save</button>
            <button class="clearButton" id="ClearSearch">Clear</button>             
        </span>
    </fieldset>    
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
html {
    background-image: url("/Images/Swiftnet-Background.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    color:#444444;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -350px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    width:704px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#wrapper{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    width:700px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;

}
#steps{
    width:700px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.step{
    float:left;
    width:700px;
}
#navigation{
    height:45px;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
#navigation ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:22px;
}
#navigation ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 2px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display:block;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#444;
    color:#777;
    outline:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:45px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    background:
        -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.09, rgb(240,240,240)),
        color-stop(0.55, rgb(227,227,227)),
        color-stop(0.78, rgb(240,240,240))
        );
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(240,240,240) 9%,
        rgb(227,227,227) 55%,
        rgb(240,240,240) 78%
        )
}
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li.selected a{
    background:#d8d8d8;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
span.checked{
    background:transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:1px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
span.error{
    background:transparent url(../images/error.png) no-repeat top left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:1px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
#steps form fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#steps form legend{
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    color:#666;
    font-size:24px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px 20px -20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
#steps form p{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:5px 0px;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width:400px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
}
#steps form p label{
    width:160px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:15px;
    line-height:26px;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#steps form input:not([type=radio]),
#steps form textarea,
#steps form select{
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
#steps form input:focus{
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background-color:#FFFEEF;
}
#steps form p.submit{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
#steps form button {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*display: inline;*/
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:100px;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background:#4797ED;
}
#steps form button:hover {
    background:#d8d8d8;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

#steps form input[readonly="readonly"]{
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}

#ButtonContainer {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

/*.button {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background:#4797ED;
}*/


/* TABLES */
.inlineTable {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

/* FORMS */
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
}

.editor-box-label 
{
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #696969;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    color: Black;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following addition to your CSS:

```css
.ButtonContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 0; /* adjust as needed */
}
.ButtonContainer button {
    margin: 0 10px; /* adjust as needed */
}
.ButtonContainer:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2xXCD/

Turn the `.ButtonContainer` element into a block level element with 100% width and set `overflow: auto` (or `clear: both`) to clear the floated inline tables.

Use `text-align: justify` to get the evenly spaced buttons.

However, this only works if there are more than two rows in the container, so use a pseudo-element to generate an empty 100% wide inline-block of zero height.

Tweak the margin and padding as needed to get the correct white space balance.

Works in most modern browsers.

In Firefox, it looks like:

[image]

Comment: If I needed to add a fourth button which CSS property should I adjust to allow for that? Complete noob at CSS so appreciate the post.

Comment: Just add the extra buttons (within reason) and they will space themselves out evenly, it's a rather neat little trick.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your HTML and CSS.

Your CSS references `#steps` when there is no element with id `steps`. Your form is id `formElem1`. Replace `#steps form` or `#steps` with `#formElem1` in your CSS.

### JSFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/x3Dus/)

Without fixing your CSS, this is a hack but it works. I recommend you adjusting your CSS and HTML accordingly

## HTML

```
<span class="ButtonContainer">
    <button type="submit" class="submitButton submitButton--1" >Search</button>
    <button type="submit" class="submitButton submitButton--2" >Save</button>
    <button class="clearButton" id="ClearSearch">Clear</button>             
</span>
```

## CSS

```
.submitButton,
.clearButton {
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.submitButton--1 {
    left: -403px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.submitButton--2 {
    left: -125px;
}
.clearButton {
    left: 150px;
}
```

### JSFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/LCcBM/) (Unelegant solution)

Comment: There are extra elements in the CSS that are used in the layout. Just trying to focus on this individual fieldset. What you see in the fiddle is how it displays on the page.

Comment: Yeah... that's not what I'm going for. I want the tables to display side by side and the buttons below the lowest input box on the page. Your fiddle shows the tables stacked vertically on one half of the page and the buttons doing the same on the right half.

Comment: I posted a working solution but again, I'd recommend you adjust your CSS and HTML accordingly before tackling this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS,
also change your #ButtonContainer to .ButtonContainer

**CSS**

```
.ButtonContainer button{
    width:32%;
}
```

now put the ButtonContainer in another table row

**HTML**

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="ButtonContainer">
            <button type="submit" class="submitButton" >Search</button>
            <button type="submit" class="submitButton" >Save</button>
            <button class="clearButton" id="ClearSearch">Clear</button>      
     </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Am8vc/3/)